# Two QML Video elements work fine on desktop but not on Android

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtmultimedia

We want to have multiple simultaneous video playbacks in our application.
This example below runs fine on Mac but on Android, I see only video in the left QML `Video` element.

I notice, from the signals, that both players enter the `PlayingState`.
I also note that, on Android, the `status=MediaPlayer.Buffering` while on Mac `status=MediaPlayer.Buffered`. However, the same statuses are also observed when a single `Video` element is used hence I don't think this difference is relevant here.

Is this a Qt bug or a platform limitation?
Can I detect this platform limitation somehow (in order to adapt the UI accordingly)?

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.5

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Video {
        id: v1
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height
        anchors.left: parent.left
        source: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"
        onStatusChanged: console.log("Status V1 "+status + "//" + MediaPlayer.Buffering)
        onAvailabilityChanged: console.log("Availability V1 "+availability)
        onErrorChanged: console.log("Error V1 "+error + "//"+ errorString)
        onPlaybackStateChanged: console.log("PlaybackState V1 "+playbackState)
    }
    Video {
        id: v2
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height
        anchors.right: parent.right
        source: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"
        onStatusChanged: console.log("Status V2 "+status + "//" + MediaPlayer.Buffering)
        onErrorChanged: console.log("Error V2 "+error + "//"+ errorString)
        onPlaybackStateChanged: console.log("PlaybackState V2 "+playbackState)
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        v1.play()
        v2.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find anything to solve this for Android?

Comment: I created (just now) a Qt bug report for it: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56627